# Cuda-related compling errors in Qt5 with OpenCV3.4.5

Tags: qt, opencv

I build OpenCV3.4.5 with Cuda support enabled, with VS2015 and Cuda8.0 (refer to this post [How to Build OpenCV for Windows with CUDA](https://pterneas.com/2018/11/02/opencv-cuda/)). The whole building process proceed without errors, with Build: 605 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped. For your information, the building configurations for OpenCV3.4.5 are given in the following:

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.5 =====================================
  --   Version control:               unknown
  --
  --   Platform:
  --     Timestamp:                   2019-01-09T23:07:28Z
  --     Host:                        Windows 10.0.17134 AMD64
  --     CMake:                       3.9.1
  --     CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
  --     CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
  --     MSVC:                        1900
  --
  --   CPU/HW features:
  --     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
  --       requested:                 SSE3
  --     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
  --       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
  --       SSE4_1 (6 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
  --       SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
  --       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
  --       AVX (6 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
  --       AVX2 (12 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
  --
  --   C/C++:
  --     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
  --     C++11:                       YES
  --     C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24215.1)
  --     C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi      /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP4   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
  --     C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi      /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP4   /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
  --     C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
  --     C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi        /MP4    /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
  --     C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi        /MP4  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
  --     Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO
  --     Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL
  --     ccache:                      NO
  --     Precompiled headers:         NO
  --     Extra dependencies:          cudart.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppicom.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib cufft.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/lib/x64
  --     3rdparty dependencies:
  --
  --   OpenCV modules:
  --     To be built:                 calib3d core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev dnn features2d flann highgui imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator ml objdetect photo python3 python_bindings_generator shape stitching superres ts video videoio videostab world
  --     Disabled:                    -
  --     Disabled by dependency:      -
  --     Unavailable:                 java js python2 python2 viz
  --     Applications:                tests perf_tests examples apps
  --     Documentation:               NO
  --     Non-free algorithms:         NO
  --
  --   Windows RT support:            NO
  --
  --   GUI:
  --     QT:                          YES (ver 5.7.0)
  --       QT OpenGL support:         NO
  --     Win32 UI:                    YES
  --     VTK support:                 NO
  --
  --   Media I/O:
  --     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
  --     JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
  --     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
  --     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.35)
  --     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
  --     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
  --     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
  --     HDR:                         YES
  --     SUNRASTER:                   YES
  --     PXM:                         YES
  --
  --   Video I/O:
  --     DC1394:                      NO
  --     FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
  --       avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.107.100)
  --       avformat:                  YES (ver 57.83.100)
  --       avutil:                    YES (ver 55.78.100)
  --       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.8.100)
  --       avresample:                YES (ver 3.7.0)
  --     GStreamer:                   NO
  --     DirectShow:                  YES
  --     Media Foundation:            YES
  --       DXVA:                      YES
  --
  --   Parallel framework:            Concurrency
  --
  --   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
  --
  --   Other third-party libraries:
  --     Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
  --            at:                   E:/In-Field-Sorting-Pro/OpenCV/opencv-3.4.5/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
  --     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
  --               at:                E:/In-Field-Sorting-Pro/OpenCV/opencv-3.4.5/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
  --     Lapack:                      NO
  --     Eigen:                       NO
  --     Custom HAL:                  NO
  --     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
  --
  --   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 8.0, CUFFT CUBLAS NVCUVID FAST_MATH)
  --     NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 30 35 37 50 52 60 61
  --     NVIDIA PTX archs:
  --
  --   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
  --     Include path:                E:/In-Field-Sorting-Pro/OpenCV/opencv-3.4.5/sources/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
  --     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
  --
  --   Python 3:
  --     Interpreter:                 C:/Python35/python3.exe (ver 3.5.4)
  --     Libraries:                   C:/Python35/libs/python35.lib (ver 3.5.4)
  --     numpy:                       C:/Python35/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.1)
  --     install path:                C:/Python35/Lib/site-packages/cv2/python-3.5
  --
  --   Python (for build):            C:/Python35/python3.exe
  --
  --   Java:
  --     ant:                         NO
  --     JNI:                         NO
  --     Java wrappers:               NO
  --     Java tests:                  NO
  --
  --   Install to:                    C:/opencv-3.4.5/mybuild
```

With Qt5.7 and the self-build OpenCV3.4.5, compiling my Qt project results in hundreds of cuda-related errors, part of which (e.g., `C2061: syntax error: identifier) are shown below:

```
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'min'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): error C2182: 'InputArray': illegal use of type 'void'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src2'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): error C2086: 'int cv::cuda::InputArray': redefinition
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): note: see declaration of 'cv::cuda::InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'src2'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'max'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): error C2182: 'InputArray': illegal use of type 'void'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): error C2086: 'int cv::cuda::InputArray': redefinition
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): note: see declaration of 'cv::cuda::InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): error C2086: 'int cv::cuda::src1': redefinition
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(296): note: see declaration of 'cv::cuda::src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src2'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(307): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'src2'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(330): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(334): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(335): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(335): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(351): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(361): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'xy'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(369): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'xy'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(379): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'x'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(389): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'x'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(401): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'x'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(414): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'x'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(425): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'magnitude'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(453): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(455): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(465): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(480): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(494): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(501): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'lut'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(518): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(534): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(536): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(546): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(548): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(557): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(559): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(566): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(568): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(575): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(577): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(590): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(592): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(607): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(610): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(621): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(623): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(651): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'mtx'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(661): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'mtx'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(663): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'mtx'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(673): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(691): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(703): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(712): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(744): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(761): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(778): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src1'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(815): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'src'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(828): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp(861): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudabgsegm.hpp(85): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudabgsegm.hpp(132): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudafilters.hpp(84): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudafilters.hpp(120): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudafilters.hpp(159): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudafilters.hpp(261): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudafeatures2d.hpp(154): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
c:\opencv-3.4.5\mybuild\include\opencv2/cudafeatures2d.hpp(160): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'InputArray'
```

It is noted that my projects works fine with officially prebuilt OpenCV3.4.5 that comes without Cuda support! So these errors must be because of the cuda-enabled opencv building.

What is confusing to me is that my project does not explicitly involve cuda computations, and I also did not include any cuda-related headers (my OpenCV build generates single `opencv_world345` files). One possible guess for these errors is inappropriate include headers, e.g., `#include <windows.h>`.

Has anyone encountered similar errors? How to resolve them if I want to keep cuda functionalities, rather that using the prebuild version?

Comment: There are no "CUDA related"  errors in the compiler output you have posted. I have removed the tag

Comment: I just simply take those errors (e.g., C2146) happening to opencv2 cuda-related header files are 'CUDA related' error. I am not sure of exact reasons for these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>

//or 
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a similar problem, and I could find a way to solve it.
In my case, I am building in a same project sometimes a ".dll", sometimes an ".exe" for Windows with VS2015. I was building the project as an exe when the error appeared. Then I just switched my project to be built as a DLL, and building this way I've got more meaningful errors !
To build a DLL in VS2015 :

> Project->Properties(ALT+F7)->Configuration Properties(column on the
>   left)->General -> General -> Target Extension : .dll "->General ->
>   ProjectDefaults -> Configuration Type : Dynamic Library (.dll)
>   "->Configuration Properties(column on the
>   left)->Linker->System->SubSystem : Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)

You'll probably need to set your C++ objects as "DLL exportable" ; to do so :

```
 //define it when you build as DLL
// undefine it when you build as an exe and undo the steps above in the Project Properties
#define DLL

#ifdef DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)    //shortens __declspec(dllexport) to DLL_EXPORT
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT 
#endif 


#ifdef __cplusplus  //if C++ is used convert it to C to prevent C++'s name mangling of method names
extern "C"
{
#endif

class DLL_EXPORT MaGamesClass
{
public:
  /* your class, as usual */
    MaGamesClass();
    ~MaGamesClass();

    float _soon = 2019;
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In my case, one of my DLL exported class has some parameters in its constructor ; I discovered that DLL exported classes don't like that....

Thus, I just add a few functions to act as the constructor, for all my needs : 
MaGames.h :

```
public : 
        MaGamesClass();
    //Because parameters cannot be set to constructor in DLL (->build error)
    static MaGamesClass MaGamesClass_instantiate(std::string where);
    static MaGamesClass* MaGamesClass_new(std::string where);
        /*
             Return this
        */
    MaGamesClass* init(std::string where);
    ~MaGamesClass();

/*
Some guys prefer initialisation of members in the constructor (MaGamesClass MaGamesClass(): _soon(2019){ ... }
I prefered here to avoid as much as possible constructor's build errors
And i find it's more readable anyway :p
*/
      float _soon = 2019; //
      std::string _where;
```

MaGames.cpp :

```
using namespace std;

MaGames MaGames::MaGames_instantiate(string where)
{
    MaGames vrSport= MaGames();
    return *vrSport.init(where);
}

MaGames MaGames::MaGames_new(string where){
    MaGames* vrSport= new MaGames();
    return vrSport->init(where);
}

MaGames * MaGames ::init(string where)
{
    _where = where;
        return this;
}
```

Examples of usage :

```
MaGames myCenter = MaGamesClass::MaGamesClass_instantiate("France");
MaGames* myCenter = MaGamesClass::MaGamesClass_new("Closer?");
```

Voila voila, hope this helps guys

Dream,Go, AndHaveFun

Comment: PS : This did not solve my problem for building as an exe application ; it's just a workaround, and knowing it works as a DLL but not as an exe can give some clues about the resolution

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who meet this problem my solution was to include `cudaarithm.hpp` BEFORE `opencv.hpp` or *any other included header* with `opencv.hpp` in it. This is not completely clear in accepted answer of @jingweimo

Answer (score 0):

```
too many actual parameters for macro 'max'
```

maybe there is a conflict defintion between a function named min and the macro definied in somewhat file you have included, probably defined into windows api headers.

You can try to compile your project using **NOMINMAX** in the preprocessor part of your project.

Comment: I am working with QtCreator 4.5 for compiling the project. Add #define NOMINMAX does not resolve these errors.

Comment: ok, can you put a MCVE, with .cpp and .pro files which describes the problem, so people can try to reproduce your behaviour at home. Moreover the position of your define is important. To be sure this definition is at the top of your project don't define it yourself in the code, but add it to your preprocessor definitions in your .pro file using DEFINES += "NOMINMAX"